# log tan(x) partial integration

Tags: integration

What is $\int \frac {log(tan(x)) tan(x)}{cos^2x} dx$.

I think it should be done partially, but taking $f(x)=tan(x) \space , g(x)=log(tan(x)) tan(x)$ I get:$$tan^2(x)log(tan(x))-\int tan(x)(tan'(x)+\frac{log(tan(x))}{cos^2(x)})dx$$

And here I am stuck. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $\frac{dx}{\cos^2x}=\tan'(x)dx$ so let $u=\tan(x)$ the integral becomes

$$\int u\ln(u)du$$
and by integrating by parts you get the result.